# Iterating over numpy array keeping the indices

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
n_samples, n_rows, n_cols, n_boxes_per_cell, _ = Y_pred.shape
    for example in range(n_samples):
        for x_grid in range(n_rows):
            for y_grid in range(n_cols):
                for bnd_box in range(n_boxes_per_cell):
                    bnd_box_label = Y_pred[example, x_grid, y_grid, bnd_box]
                    do_some_stuff(bnd_box_label, x_grid, y_grid)
```

How can I get functionally equivalent code with at most one explicit iteration? Notice that I need the indices `x_grid` and `y_grid`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.ndindex`:

```
for example, x_grid, y_grid, bnd_box in np.ndindex(Y_pred.shape[:4]):
    etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can always build a generator out of multiple iterables:

```
all_combinations = ((a, b, c, d) for a in range(n_samples)
                                 for b in range(n_rows) 
                                 for c in range(n_cols) 
                                 for d in range(n_boxes_per_cell))

for examples, x_grid, y_grid, bnd_box in all_combinations:
    do stuff
```

This is the same as using itertools.product(*iterables) and valid for any iterable, not just iteration over indices/integers.